# Android: accessing NMEA data from bluetooth GPS

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, gps, nmea

I need to access the NMEA strings from a connected Bluetooth GPS Receiver. Note: this is for a cordova application.

- I have successfully connected the receiver to the Android device
  using the Android app *Bluetooth GPS*.
- I have successfully used the receiver in my app by allowing *Mock GPS Provider*.
- I can successfully get the NMEA data from the device's internal GPS, but when I enable *Mock GPS Provider* the NmeaListener stops firing.

#### Environment:

- Samsung SM-T700
- Android 4.4.2
- Cordova 3.3.1
- Receiver Arrow 100

#### Code

```
package org.apache.cordova.nmea;


import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener;

import android.util.Log;

public class Nmea extends CordovaPlugin implements NmeaListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private CallbackContext savedCallbackContext;

    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action        The action to execute.
     * @param args      JSONArry of arguments for the plugin.
     * @param callbackContext   The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
     * @return          True if the action was valid, or false if not.
     */
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        this.savedCallbackContext = callbackContext;

        if (this.locationManager == null) {
            this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        if (action.equals("setNmeaListener")) {
            Log.w("NMEA", "setNmeaListerer fired");
            this.locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);             
        }

        return true;
    }
    public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
        Log.w("Nmea", nmea);
        this.win(nmea);
    }
    private void win(String message) {
        // Success return object
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, message);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.savedCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
    }
}
```

#### Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```